# Desktop server and android client local connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

i try to connect my windows desktop java server from android client. I'm working cross-platform. Desktop server and desktop client working fine with same code, but desktop server and android client has a interesting problem. manifest permissions is setted.

Desktop java server code

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(tcp_port);
Socket link = null;
while(true) {
     link = serverSocket.accept();
     PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true); // flush true
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream()));
     // step 1 password auth
     String message = input.readLine(); // wait password
     if(message.equals(password)) {
           output.println("correct");

           message = null;
           message = input.readLine(); // wait udp port request
           if(message.equals("UDP")) {
                output.println(udp_port+"");
etc
.
.
```

Android client code

```
Socket link = null; 
link = new Socket(hostip,tcp_port);
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true); // auto flush true
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream()));
while(true) {
     // step1 send the password wait the response
     output.println(password);
     String message = input.readLine(); // password response
     if(message.equals("correct")) {
          output.println("UDP"); // request udp
          message = null;
          message = input.readLine();
          udpport = Integer.parseInt(message);

etc
.
.
```

My problem is same code works fine on java desktop client and java desktop server but 
when i try to connect java desktop server from android client password auth part works fine but

output.println(udp_port+""); send data two times when i looked to the server side it sends empty string firstly and then sends my value what is wrong ?

```
       message = null;
       message = input.readLine(); // wait udp port request
       if(message.equals("UDP")) {
```

it reads the empty string and jump the if statement but if i use

```
       message = null;
       message = input.readLine(); // read empty string
       message = input.readLine(); // read my data
       if(message.equals("UDP")) {
            statement works
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior if you try to read the data before it has been received - something that is more likely to occur when receiving from a remote system, but always a possibility you must allow for.

Your application must wait until a full message has been collected, in this case probably by looping on the readLine() call until you get a non-null message.

Comment: thx for the answer, for(;;) { message = input.readLine(); if(!message.equals("")) { break; } } this code solve my problem thx again.